# What are the blocks in this diagonal block form and how can they be used to find invariant subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Considering $T :$ $\mathbb{R}^6$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^6$
with standard matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}6 & 0 &4 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\-4 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-4 & 0 & -8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$

What are the blocks in this block diagonal form? How would you use them to find T - invariant subspaces?

Answer (score 2):

Write the matrix as
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c|c}
6 & 0 &4 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\-4 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-4 & 0 & -8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 &0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0
\end{array}\right]
$$
$4 \times 4$, $1\times 1$, and $1 \times 1$ matrices on the diagonal are the blocks. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis vectors. Based on this block diagonal form, we can deduce that
$$
\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}, \quad \operatorname{span}\{e_5\}, \quad \operatorname{span}\{e_6\}
$$
are each $T$-invariant subspaces. Looking at the $4 \times 4$ submatrix yeilds further $T$-invariant subspaces within the $4$-dimensional space.